# NHibernate take the top 20 from results

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

I am using WCF calls to the server to retrive records.

This is done through Nhibernate.

How do I limit the query result that I am getting to say only return the first 20 records.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you query, with QueryOver:

```
var rates = session
            .QueryOver<ExchangeRate>()
            .OrderBy(r => r.ExchangeDate).Desc
            .ThenBy(r => r.CurrencyId.CurrencyId).Asc
            .Take(20)
            .List();
```

With the ICreateria interface you can do it by making a createria